# Expo how to navigate between screens

Tags: react-native, expo

So I've created three separate pages within the app and I've also added a Stack Navigator from React Native, but when I click on the button the app doesn't change page. As this is my first app in React any help would be massively appreciated!

This is what my Add.js looks like;

```
import React from "react";
import { YellowBox } from "react-native";
import { Font } from "expo";
import Timer from "./src/screens/Timer";
import Splash from "./src/screens/Splash";
import Main from "./src/screens/Main";

import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
const DrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
  Timer: {
    screen: Timer
  },
  Splash: {
    screen: Splash
  },
  Main: {
    screen: Main
  }
});
const StackNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    DrawerNavigation: {
      screen: DrawerNavigation`enter code here`
    },
    Timer: {
      screen: Timer
    },
    Splash: {
      screen: Splash
    },
    Main: {
      screen: Main
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fontLoaded: false
    };
    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
      "Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated",
      "Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated",
      "Warning: componentWillUpdate is deprecated"
    ]);
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("./src/assets/fonts/Arial.ttf") 
/*FallbackFont*/`
    });

    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    console.warn("Fallback font is being used. Please check App.js 
file.");
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.fontLoaded ? <StackNavigation /> : 
<Expo.AppLoading />;
  }
}
```

And here is the Main.js;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button15 from "../symbols/button15";
import { Center } from "@builderx/utils";
import Button52 from "../symbols/button52";
import { View, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Image, ScrollView } from 
"react-native";

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="dark-content"
          style={styles.statusBar}
          animated={true}
        />
        <Button15
          style={styles.button15}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.pop();
          }}
        />
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollArea} horizontal={false} />
        <Center horizontal>
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/DLLargeDarK.jpeg")}
            style={styles.image}
          />
        </Center>
        <Center horizontal>
          <View style={styles.rect3}>
            <View style={styles.rect} />
            <Center horizontal>
              <Button52
                style={styles.button52}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.props.navigation.push("Timer");
                }}
              />
            </Center>
            <View style={styles.rect2} />
          </View>
        </Center>
        <Center>
          <View style={styles.rect4}>
            <View style={styles.rect5} />
            <Button52
              style={styles.button522}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.push("Timer");
              }}
            />
            <View style={styles.rect6} />
          </View>
        </Center>
        <Center horizontal>
          <View style={styles.rect7}>
            <View style={styles.rect8} />
            <Button52
              style={styles.button523}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.push("Timer");
              }}
            />
            <View style={styles.rect9} />
          </View>
        </Center>
        <Center horizontal>
          <View style={styles.rect10}>
            <View style={styles.rect11} />
            <Button52
              style={styles.button524}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.push("Timer");
              }}
            />
            <View style={styles.rect12} />
          </View>
        </Center>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#f3f4f4",
    flex: 1
  },

  statusBar: {},
  button15: {
    top: 56,
    left: 338,
    position: "absolute",
    height: 36
  },
  scrollArea: {
    height: 608.9,
    width: 374,
    top: 156,
    left: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(244,244,245,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  image: {
    height: 73,
    width: 301,
    position: "absolute",
    top: "6.83%"
  },
  rect3: {
    height: 133,
    width: 347,
    top: 156,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect: {
    top: 0,
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 91,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  button52: {
    top: 91,
    height: 36,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect2: {
    top: "95.52%",
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 6,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  rect4: {
    width: 347,
    height: 132,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect5: {
    top: 0,
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 91,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  button522: {
    top: 91,
    left: "37.46%",
    height: 35,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect6: {
    top: "95.52%",
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 6,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  rect7: {
    top: "61.33%",
    width: 347,
    height: 133,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect8: {
    top: 0,
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 91,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  button523: {
    top: 91,
    left: "37.46%",
    height: 35,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect9: {
    top: "95.52%",
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 6,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  rect10: {
    top: "81.16%",
    width: 347,
    height: 133,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect11: {
    top: 0,
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 91,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  },
  button524: {
    top: 91,
    left: "37.46%",
    height: 35,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rect12: {
    top: "95.52%",
    left: "0%",
    width: 347,
    height: 6,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    opacity: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: it should be this.props.navigation.navigate('Timer');

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, unfortunately even with that change the app still doesn't navigate as it should. The button remains clickable but there is no outcome after pressing it.

Answer (score 0):

In React Navigation you need to use the `navigate` method instead of `push`

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Timer");
```

And to go back you use the `goBack` method instead of `pop`

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

[Read more about the `navigation` prop in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! After that change the app still doesn't navigate. The app compiles and the button is clickable but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: then there is some other issue in your code. You should be importing and call `createStackNavigator` and `createDrawerNavigator` but it looks like you're importing `StackNavigator` and `DrawerNavigator` instead, that could be the issue

Comment: upon your advice I've corrected the issues with the navigation, however now when compiling I'm getting an the following error:

Unsupported top level event type "topTouchStart" dispatched